# How to clean Cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra

```
> Blockquote
users-6521507045b511e9b987d3bcf2375bd1
users-86d8a89045af11e9b987d3bcf2375bd1
users-e3548ac045b011e9b987d3bcf2375bd1
```

cassandra create multiple directories, how to delete the unused directory?

Comment: What's wrong with deleting the directory as you'd normally delete a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra keeps deleted data as a safe guard whend dropping or truncating tables / keyspaces.

If you look inside those directories you will find them empty apart from a snapshots:

```
.
./backups
./snapshots
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted/mc-1-big-Digest.crc32
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted/mc-1-big-Statistics.db
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted/mc-1-big-Data.db
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted/mc-1-big-Filter.db
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted/mc-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted/mc-1-big-TOC.txt
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted/mc-1-big-Index.db
./snapshots/dropped-1546614808079-compacted/mc-1-big-Summary.db
```

`nodetool clearsnapshot` will remove those snapshots. After that I use a simple `find /var/lib/cassandra/data**/ -type d -empty -print` to clean things up. But be careful when there are new tables and keyspaces generated als this deletes their folders as well - and I don't know how Cassandra handles that.